# VB6 dependencies to access a network postgresql database

Tags: postgresql, vb6, ado

I have a vb6 application that will be accessing a network Postgresl 9.3 database via ADO.
This is a portion of the connection string

> Provider=MSDASQL;Driver={PostgreSQL ANSI}

What (if anything) do I need to distribute with my application to guarantee that the provider/driver combination will be present on windows machines (xp and up)?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bundle the psqlODBC MSI:

http://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/msi/

Just run it with `msiexec /i THEDRIVERMSI.msi /passive /n` from your installer.

It comes with the required `libpq`, OpenSSL, etc. You might need to make sure the correct Visual Studio runtime is installed, I don't remember if it auto-installs that.

If you want to make it invisible to users, bundle it as an `msm` that becomes just another component of your application's MSI installer. You have to recompile psqlODBC to generate the msm, see the `winbuild` and `installer` folders in the source code.